# Reading a (Wireshark) LiveCapture of USB keystrokes into python on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, keyboard, usb, wireshark, tshark

### Context

The bluetooth of my keyboard is unstable, it's a known problem of the device. The manufacturer says the micro-USB does not transmit keypresses and that it is for charging only. However, I inspected the USB data with Wireshark and detected it does transmit the keystrokes over its micro-USB connection. So I am trying to give the keyboard a second life through the micro-USB connection (and hopefully help people with the same issue).

### System

Ubuntu 20.04

### Approach

I've identified the USB port of my keyboard device in Wireshark, and recorded the stream of data across that port. That data is saved into a file called `abcd.pcapng` (I pressed the buttons `abcd` during the recording). Next, I wrote a basic python script that uses `tshark` to convert `abcd.pcapng` file into its original keypresses `abcd`.

### Code

This is the Python code that converts the `abcd.pcapng` file into the letters `abcd`:

```
# This script extracts the keypresses from a pcapng file.
import os

pcapng_filename = "abcd.pcapng"
keypress_ids_filename = "keypress_ids.txt"

# create the output for
command_pcapng_to_keypress_ids = (
    f"tshark -r '{pcapng_filename}' -T fields -e usb.capdata > {keypress_ids_filename}"
)
print(
    f"Running the following bash command to convert the pcapng file to 00xx00000 nrs:\n{command_pcapng_to_keypress_ids}"
)
os.system(command_pcapng_to_keypress_ids)

# read keypress id file
switcher = {
    "04": "a",  # or A
    "05": "b",  # or B
    "06": "c",  # or C
    "07": "d",  # or D
    "08": "e",  # or E
    "09": "f",  # or F
    "0A": "g",  # or G
    "0B": "h",  # or H
    "0C": "i",  # or I
    "0D": "j",  # or J
    "0E": "k",  # or K
    "0F": "l",  # or L
    "10": "m",  # or M
    "11": "n",  # or N
    "12": "o",  # or O
    "13": "p",  # or P
    "14": "q",  # or Q
    "15": "r",  # or R
    "16": "s",  # or S
    "17": "t",  # or T
    "18": "u",  # or U
    "19": "v",  # or V
    "1A": "w",  # or W
    "1B": "x",  # or X
    "1C": "y",  # or Y
    "1D": "x",  # or Z
    "1E": "1",  # or !
    "1F": "2",  # or @
    "20": "3",  # or #
    "21": "4",  # or $
    "22": "5",  # or %
    "23": "6",  # or ^
    "24": "7",  # or &
    "25": "8",  # or *
    "26": "9",  # or (
    "27": "0",  # or )
    "2D": "-",  # or _
    "2E": "+",  # or =
    "2F": "[",  # or {
    "30": "]",  # or }
    "31": '"',  # or |
    "33": ";",  # or :
    "34": "'",  # or "
    "35": "`",  # or ~
    "36": ",",  # or <
    "37": ".",  # or >
    "38": "/",  # or ?
}


def readFile(filename):
    fileOpen = open(filename)
    return fileOpen


file = readFile(keypress_ids_filename)
print(f"file={file}")

# parse the 0000050000000000 etc codes and convert them into keystrokes
for line in file:
    if len(line) == 17:
        two_chars = line[4:6]
        try:
            print(
                f"line={line[0:16]}, relevant characters indicating keypress ID: {two_chars} convert keypres ID to letter: {switcher[two_chars]}"
            )
        except:
            pass
```

### Output

The output of that script for the specified file is:

```
Running the following bash command to convert the pcapng file to 00xx00000 nrs:
tshark -r 'abcd.pcapng' -T fields -e usb.capdata > keypress_ids.txt
file=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='keypress_ids.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
line=0000040000000000, relevant characters indicating keypress ID: 04 convert keypres ID to letter: a
line=0000050000000000, relevant characters indicating keypress ID: 05 convert keypres ID to letter: b
line=0000060000000000, relevant characters indicating keypress ID: 06 convert keypres ID to letter: c
line=0000070000000000, relevant characters indicating keypress ID: 07 convert keypres ID to letter: d
```

### Question

How can I adjust the code to get the USB data directly as a continuous stream, instead of first having to start- and stop recording the USB data followed by having to create the output `abcd.pcapng` file?

For example, is there a Wireshark-api or tshark function that starts listening until the/some script is stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The following script called `live_capture_keystrokes.py` captures the `Leftover Capture Data` which contains the signals of the keystrokes, they are parsed live and continuously by the Python code.

I think it is important to activate usb monitoring each time you reboot the computer (if you want to run this script successfully). To do that, you can run:

```
sudo modprobe usbmon
```

Ideally you would run that without sudo, that would also prevent one to run the python file with sudo, but I did not yet figure out how to run `modprobe usbmon` without sudo.

### Code

This `live_capture_keystrokes.py` script needs to be ran with sudo if `modprobe usbmon` is ran with sudo. To run the python script in sudo, one can type:

```
sudo su
# sudo apt install python3
# pip install pyshark
# python3 live_capture_keystrokes.py
```

And the content of `live_capture_keystrokes.py` is:

```
import pyshark
# Get keystrokes data
print("\n----- Capturing keystrokes from usbmon0 --------------------")
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='usbmon0', output_file='output.pcap')

# Source: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/92561/pyshark.LiveCapture 
for i, packet in enumerate(capture.sniff_continuously()):
    try:
        data= packet[1].usb_capdata.split(":")
        print(data)
    except:
        pass
capture.clear()
capture.close()
print(f'DONE')
```

### Output

The output is not yet parsed back to keystrokes, I will add that later. However, this is the output, each time you press a key on your usb keyboard, it prints the accompanying list directly to screen.

```
a['00', '00', '04', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
b['00', '00', '05', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
c['00', '00', '06', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
d['00', '00', '07', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
e['00', '00', '08', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
f['00', '00', '09', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
g['00', '00', '0a', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
h['00', '00', '0b', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
i['00', '00', '0c', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
j['00', '00', '0d', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
k['00', '00', '0e', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
l['00', '00', '0f', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
m['00', '00', '10', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
n['00', '00', '11', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
o['00', '00', '12', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
p['00', '00', '13', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
q['00', '00', '14', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
r['00', '00', '15', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
s['00', '00', '16', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
t['00', '00', '17', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
u['00', '00', '18', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
v['00', '00', '19', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
w['00', '00', '1a', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
x['00', '00', '1b', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
y['00', '00', '1c', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
z['00', '00', '1d', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
0['00', '00', '62', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
1['00', '00', '59', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
2['00', '00', '5a', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
3['00', '00', '5b', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
4['00', '00', '5c', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
5['00', '00', '5d', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
6['00', '00', '5e', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
7['00', '00', '5f', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
8['00', '00', '60', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
9['00', '00', '61', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
1['00', '00', '1e', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
2['00', '00', '1f', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
3['00', '00', '20', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
4['00', '00', '21', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
5['00', '00', '22', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
6['00', '00', '23', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
7['00', '00', '24', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
8['00', '00', '25', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
9['00', '00', '26', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
0['00', '00', '27', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
```